# How to validate CaptchaBundle via AJAX?

Tags: ajax, validation, symfony

I'm trying to write form and submit it, validate form via AJAX using Symfony2 and CaptchaBundle. Can anybody give me a hint gow to do this. Any tutorial?

Comment: actually I don't know how to start. I've just migrate myself from symfony 1.4 to symfony 2. Previously I used input by input validation and I'm wondering if symfony2 has method to validate form with capatch... any ideas?

Comment: Which "[CaptchaBundle](https://packagist.org/search/?q=captcha)" are you refering to?

Comment: https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle